# ipv6 static ip assignment failing on router NIC

Tags: ipv6, static-ip

I'm working on configuring a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running the latest rasbian as a router since my current home router is degrading and it's a fun project. Never done much with networking before but I got the pi set up up to do ipv4 routing without too much issue, only to realize my ISP is using ipv6 in my area. For some reason assigning a static ipv6 address to the local lan interface isn't working. I'm assigning the static addresses in

/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0:

```
allow-hotplug eth0

iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.3.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.3.1


iface eth0 inet6 static
    address fd00:3::1/64
    gateway fd00:3::1
    accept_ra 0
```

The ipv6 config seems pretty similar to the working ipv4 but it refuses to take effect:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.1/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe1a:7d3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I added and removed options to match examples I found online but nothing has worked. I do notice this in journalctl:

```
Jan 16 16:17:05 router kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jan 16 16:17:05 router avahi-daemon[322]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jan 16 16:17:05 router avahi-daemon[322]: Registering new address record for 192.168.4.1 on wlan0.IPv4.
Jan 16 16:17:05 router sh[395]: Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
Jan 16 16:17:05 router sh[395]: ifup: failed to bring up eth0
Jan 16 16:17:05 router systemd[1]: ifup@eth0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 16 16:17:05 router systemd[1]: ifup@eth0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The gateway setting seems to make sense to me so not sure what it's complaining about, possibly that's just a red herring?

I also have radvd running with the following config:

```
interface eth0 {
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    MinRtrAdvInterval 3;
    MaxRtrAdvInterval 10;
    prefix fd00:3::/64 {
        AdvOnLink on;
        AdvAutonomous on;
        AdvRouterAddr on;
    };

    # OpenDNS
    RDNSS 2620:119:35::35 {
    };
};
```

and clients I have connected on eth0 are getting assigned addresses, <s>but I wonder if radvd and the static assignment could be conflicting on eth0 itself?</s>

EDIT: I disabled the radvd service entirely and the interface still isn't assigned the static ip

Comment: Did [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/775058/907399) help? If not, there are [more to choose from](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=raspberry+pi+IPv6+router&ia=web)

Comment: @Seamus I've looked at a bunch of tutorials and while there are a lot of slight variations on the above `iface eth0 inet6 static` line none have worked, nor has the simple example in the interfaces(5) man page. I think the approaches that use tunnels shouldn't be necessary for me since my ISP is giving me an IPv6 address directly. As for the ones that use a DHCP service to set it, I shouldn't need to set up DHCPv6 just to assign a static ip should I?

Comment: I don't use IPv6, so take anything I say here w/ a grain of salt. But, AFAIK, `dhcpcd` handles both IPv4 and IPv6. If so, why would you not set your fixed IPADDR there? ref `man dhcpcd.conf`

Comment: "*... running the latest rasbian as a router*" - how do you run a router with only one interface **eth0**? For a router you need at least two interfaces.

Comment: @Ingo you plug in a USB to ethernet adapter.